# How to scale application for different screen sizes?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I am looking for a robust way to scale my AIR for Android app up, or down, for different screen sizes.

The app is going to be published privately, and will only likely ever sit on devices with a very small range of resolutions (720 or 1080p typically)

Now, firstly, I read that you cannot change the stage height and width dynamically and can only be set once in the application settings. So first off, do I set my app to have the largest resolution, 1080p, and scale down. Or do I set it to a mid ground between 1080 and 720 and let it scale up and down?

Secondly, how should I scale it? Should I use `Stage.scaleMode` and if so, which mode?

How do I scale the app if I cannot resize the stage directly?

I have looked at the following pages, but they don't seem to work very well, if at all, for some odd reason?

[link 1](http://gregsramblings.com/2010/05/06/scaling-an-adobe-air-application-to-fit-multiple-resolutions-and-netbooks/)
[link 2](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/multiple-screen-sizes.html)
[link 3](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/authoring_for_multiple_screen_sizes.html)
[link 4](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e31.html#WS0D75B487-23B9-402d-A52D-CB3C4CEB9EE4)

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything dynamically!

use:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT
```

and handle it yourself when the application starts. By useing relative values instead of fixed pixels, to position your items

To get the devices dimensions and DPI use:

```
Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
Capabilities.screenDPI;
```

If you're useing Bitmaps dont let them scale too much, and rather down then up.
Also checkout .smoothing attribute for Bitmaps.
its best to have different size bitmaps ready and replace them according to your screensize in some startup method.

the second link u postet acutally explains all this very well